# Как отследить выполнение нескольких функций

Tags: javascript

Есть несколько функций, которые выполняются асинхронно. Как можно отловить момент выполнения последней из функций? Например, функция sayBye должна вывестись сразу после того, как отработают все функции sayHello

```
var sayHello = function(name){
    setTimeout(()=>console.log("Hello," + name), 
                    Math.random() * (10000 - 5000) + 5000);
}

sayHello("Igor");
sayHello("Sanya");
sayHello("Vlad");
sayHello("Andrey");
sayHello("Tanya");
sayHello("Olga");
sayHello("Vanya");
sayHello("Vasya");
sayHello("Alex");
sayHello("Danil");

var sayBye = function(){
    console.log("Bye");
}

sayBye();
```

Comment: Переделать их в промисы и использовать Promise.all

Answer (score 1):

Как насчет использования `Promise`?

```
const sayHello = (name) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`Hello, ${name}`);
            resolve();
        }, Math.random() * (10000 - 5000) + 5000);
    });
};

const sayBye = () => console.log('Bye');

Promise.all([
    sayHello('Igor'),
    sayHello('Sanya'),
    sayHello('Vlad'),
    sayHello('Andrey'),
    sayHello('Tanya'),
    sayHello('Olga'),
    sayHello('Vanya'),
    sayHello('Vasya'),
    sayHello('Alex'),
    sayHello('Danil')
]).then(() => {
    sayBye();
});
```

Или же `Promise + async/await`:

```
(async () => {
    await Promise.all([
        sayHello('Igor'),
        sayHello('Sanya'),
        sayHello('Vlad'),
        sayHello('Andrey'),
        sayHello('Tanya'),
        sayHello('Olga'),
        sayHello('Vanya'),
        sayHello('Vasya'),
        sayHello('Alex'),
        sayHello('Danil')
    ]);

    sayBye();
})();
```

Comment: Это работает на хроме и на мозиле

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Вы о чем вообще? https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: @overthesanity, спасибо, понял. А можно как-то это сделать без promise.all ?

Comment: @Farad, можно, но не нативными средставми, а использовать какую-то библиотеку типа `zone.js`, которая отслеживает асинхронные таски, но это будет сложно :-)

Comment: @overthesanity, мне кажется все же можно это сделать примерно так. https://jsfiddle.net/e40os13x/30/ Я уже близок к разгадке, но что-то упускаю. Взглянете пожалуйста?

Comment: @Farad, я исправил Ваш пример, но там придется дожидаться резолвинг всех промисов "синхронно", `Promise.all` позволяет это сделать "псевдо-параллельно"

Comment: @Farad https://jsfiddle.net/e40os13x/52/

Answer (score -1):

```
function kickOff() {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
$("#output").append("start");

setTimeout(function() {
  resolve();
}, 1000);
}).then(function() {
$("#output").append(" middle");
return " end";
});
}

kickoff().then(function(result) {
// use the result here
$("#output").append(result);
 });
```

Это даст вам результат, подобный этому, в гарантированном порядке:

`start`
`middle`
`end`

Comment: Та нет...не оттуда )